# Brief, To the point, no-nonsense German grammar book written in English

Tags: book, reference-request

## EDIT

### NEWBIE ALERT: PLEASE SUGGEST ONLY ENGLISH WRITTEN BOOKS

I think the title said it all, but for the sake of completeness, i rephrase it again. I want a non-repetitive(have you seen those books that tell you something over and over like they want to hammer the material into you head?!!), brief and also complete **Grammar** textbook for a lay person like me without any prerequisite.

Comment: You need to specify in which language this book you are looking for is written. Anyway, I am afraid there is no *brief* and *complete* book at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your request is that grammar of the German language is not a rules-only thing (which then could be presented concisely indeed). The deeper you dive into the language, the more exceptions, peculiarities, things in the twilight zone of grammar and style etc. you discover, and in order to cover them, your book will get thicker and thicker. - If you want to learn a languahe with a crystal-clear and very straightforward grammar, better learn Turkish.

However, here is a book that perhaps fits more or less your needs:

> Hermann Funk, Michael Koenig, Lutz Rohrmann: Kompaktgrammatik Deutsch als Fremdsprache zum schnellen Nachschlagen. Cornelsen 2011. ISBN 978-3-5889-01636-5

Available for 9,99 Euros. Please use your local bookstore to support local business, or if necessarily ordering by mail, stay away from the large companies that smash all other businesses and do not really pay taxes; use alternative booksellers.

By the way, in a traditional bookstore you can have a look into the books to decide if they are what you are searching for.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: Funny, I just used the "Blick ins Buch" function for that book on Amazon.de. I am not saying that you are wrong, but I do not think that this belongs here.

Comment: I think the OP question is unclear. Your book is only up to B1 level and hence the opposite of *complete*. And besides, any grammar book written in German needs at least a fair knowledge of German to be able to read it, what contradicts the OP's statement *for a lay person like me without any prerequisite.*

Comment: Is this book in German? OK maybe i didn't say in the title clearly but i want the book to be in English.

Comment: @CarstenS  You are completely right that deliberations on the use of which part of market economy are not what this forum is meant for. However, in this case, I felt that when just giving the bibliographic details, everybody would scramble and thoughtelssly order it on that one and overmighty platform, and I did not want to give them this advantage. So my addition is meant to counterbalance an unfortunate implicit bias towards said platform.

Comment: @pouya  Indeed, you did not say this in the question. You are kindly invited to phrase your questions with attention. Most German grammars are in German.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann my bad so what are my options now?

Comment: @pouya  Wait for somebody to read your quesion who knows a fitting book in English? - By the way, the book I cited was written especially for people who learn German as a foreign language. I think the authors (of this book and others) suppose that people who are interested in German grammar will have at least a basic understanding of that language. And reading the book in German will further help them getting used to it.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann thanks i will add it to my book list for sure but for now i need a simple English one.